# rundll32.exe syssetup,SetupOobeBnk on another drive

Tags: windows-xp, windows-activation

I have a win XP machine that its disk is about to die.
Cloned both partitions it help using clonezilla.

Now when I start windows from the new disk I get:
`Since windows was first activated on this computer, the hardware on the computer has changed significantly. Due to these changes, window must be reactivated within 3 days.
Do you want reactivate windows now?`

Most pointers in the inet say that you can activate over the phone,
which I would gladly do (I even my product ID) but for this to work you have to be logged in.
in my case regardless of how I reply to this message It just logs me out.

I found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330136) article which recommends a repair using the original media,
but my original XP media seems to be not working any more either (`txtsetup.sif is corrupt or missing  Status 18`).

I also found several references that said that running `rundll32.exe syssetup,SetupOobeBnk` would reset the activation and allow me to login so I could complete the over the phone activation, but I am guessing this would work on the running OS.

I was wandering if there is a way to cause `rundll32.exe syssetup,SetupOobeBnk` to run on a windows installation that is not the currently running one but is on a disk connected to a machine running windows ? i.e. can I use another computer that has the OS to force the OS on some hard drive into 30 days trial before activition ?

Answer (score 4):

You can boot in safe mode with command prompt.  Type explorer.exe and then you can run:

```
rundll32.exe syssetup,SetupOobeBnk
```